# Continuations after await on UI thread - concurrency data races

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, race-condition

Imagine that I have a button click event handler like:

```
public async void btn_Click(...)
{
    await longRunningOperationAsync();
    x += 2;
}

public async void btn2_Click(...)
{
   await longRunningOperationAsync();
   x += 3;
}
```

If the user clicks btn and immediately clicks btn2 just after, does it cause data races? The statements after await will be executed concurrently (e.g. preemption) in single thread (UI), right?

However, I have read this in that website: "all of your code is running in the UI thread, so you don't have the issues with UI updates. In addition, none of your code is running concurrently, which eliminates the data integrity issues (deadlocks, race conditions) typically associated with concurrency." http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/why-net-developers-should-check-out-the-await-system/

I basically did not understand what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is no data race, because `await` will capture the UI context and resume the `async` methods in that context. You may find my [`async` introduction post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

The order in which they resume is not guaranteed, but they are not concurrent in the sense of preemption. In a UI context, you can think of the `async` method as split into several chunks (at each `await`). Each chunk will execute one at a time and cannot be preempted by another chunk.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. It is what I want. I have a small question: the context also includes the state of thread at that point, right?

Btw, what about if I put ConfigureAwait(false) in the example above. They will execute on threadpool and the chunks will not be preempted again?

Comment: The context includes the state of the method. If you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then in this example the continuations will run on thread pool threads and may preempt each other, causing a race condition.

Comment: but you said that the context also includes the state. if both methods store the state of x at the point of "await", how does the race condition happen? sorry for my low understanding:)

Comment: The race condition is due to the preemptive scheduler. The statement `x += 2` is actually equivalent to `x = x + 2`, that is, "read x, then add 2, then save to x", and the thread may be preempted at any point in that sequence.

Comment: sure, i know but my question was different. even though the context includes the state of the variables, I guess that global variables are still open to modifications from other threads. Thanks a lot!